# Boot from grub terminal on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, grub2, dual-boot

After a Kernel update my grub is broken and fedora 25 is using lvm to partition. I haven't found any tutorial that made me boot on fedora via command line on grub.

Edit:
Trying to make things more clear.
All I have when I turn on the computer is a command line "grub>" I want to know what commands should I use to boot on my fedora installation from there

Comment: *"fedora 25 is using lvm to partition"*, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, however to fix GRUB problems you can [download an ISO of boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/), burn it on a CD-ROM or USB drive, then boot from this device. Then follow the instructions.

Comment: All I have when I turn on the computer is a command line "grub>" I want to know what commands should I use to boot on my fedora installation from there

Comment: If you are in that state, it is highly likely that you *can't* boot your installation from there. The advice of using a rescue image is really the best — either that one or [rescue mode](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/26/html/Installation_Guide/sect-boot-options-rescue.html) from the Fedora [network installer](https://alt.fedoraproject.org/).

Comment: Yeah I think I'll reinstall the whole system. Thank you!